# Unexpected behaviour when Customizing ExceptionResolver in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, handlerexceptionresolver

Through the documentation of spring framework, I  got to know about customizing exception handling mechanism of spring application. As per the documentation, It is stated that spring provides some default exception Resolvers.

**SimpleMappingExceptionResolver**

A mapping between exception class names and error view names. Useful for rendering error pages in a browser application.

**DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver**

Resolves exceptions raised by Spring MVC and maps them to HTTP status codes. See also alternative ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and REST API exceptions.

**ResponseStatusExceptionResolver**

Resolves exceptions with the @ResponseStatus annotation and maps them to HTTP status codes based on the value in the annotation.

**ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver**

Resolves exceptions by invoking an @ExceptionHandler method in a @Controller or a @ControllerAdvice class. See @ExceptionHandler methods.

But in my requirement, I do not want the support of all these resolvers I just want ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver to handle the exception in my Spring Application. So for that, I have added the following Configuration in my DispatcherServlet.

**DispatcherServlet** related configuration.

```
       public void onStartup(ServletContext servletCxt) throws   {                   ServletException {
             ......
    dServlet.setDetectAllHandlerExceptionResolvers(false);
    dServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(false);
             .....
  }
```

And in my Bean configuration java class, I have created following bean.

```
      @Bean(name=DispatcherServlet.HANDLER_EXCEPTION_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
         HandlerExceptionResolver customExceptionResolver ( ) {
    return new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
}
```

In the documentation, it is stated that

/**
     * Set whether to detect all HandlerExceptionResolver beans in this servlet's context. Otherwise,
     * just a single bean with name "handlerExceptionResolver" will be expected.
     *

Default is "true". Turn this off if you want this servlet to use a single
     * HandlerExceptionResolver, despite multiple HandlerExceptionResolver beans being defined in the context.
     */

But even after all such configuration, I see HTML error pages and not JSON error response.

Sample ExceptionHandler method.

```
       @ExceptionHandler(value={NullPointerException.class})
                public ResponseEntity<Object> nullPointerExceptionHandler(NullPointerException e){
        logger.info("local exception resolver running");
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>(6);
        map.put("isSuccess",false);
        map.put("data",null);
        map.put("status",HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        map.put("message", e.getMessage());
        map.put("timestamp",new Date());
        map.put("fielderror",null);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(map,HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
    }
```

What I am doing wrong? I only need the support of ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver throughout my spring application to maintain consitency.

Comment: If you have String Security then the security errors, like Access Denied, are handled separately.

Comment: No I do not have spring security enabled.